# IMG_Load troubles (unsupported image format)

Tags: c++, linux, sdl-2, sdl-image

OS Ubuntu; IDE Codeblocks
i wrote my own texture manager class with 'load' function

```
    bool TextureManager::load(std::string fileName, std::string id, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
    {
    SDL_Surface* pTempSurface = IMG_Load(fileName.c_str());
    if(pTempSurface == NULL) {
    printf("IMAGE LOAD ERROR: %s \n", IMG_GetError());
    return false;
    }
    SDL_Texture* pTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer, pTempSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(pTempSurface);
    // everything went ok, add the texture to our list
    if(pTexture != 0) {
        m_textureMap[id] = pTexture;
        return true;
    }
    // reaching here means something went wrong
    return false;
    }
```

And it writes "IMAGE LOAD ERROR: unsupported image format"

But i included all SDL_image requires:

```
  #include <png.h>
  #include <zlib.h>
```

and without this textureloader IMG_load() worked normally.
What is that? and how can i repair it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include these headers, only SDL_image

Did you initialize it? e.g.

```
/*! initialize PNG support */
IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
```